# Unable to run Oracle VirtualBox on Windows 10 Hyper-V on Server 2012

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I am trying to get Oracle VirtualBox (6.1) to run on a Windows 10 (1909 - Build 18363.535) VM running on Server 2012 R2 (6.3 - Build 9600).

I can install and create a VM in Oracle VirtualBox. Only 32-bit OS's are available. When i try to start the OVB VM i get the following error:

```
WHvCapabilityCodeHypervisorPresent is FALSE! Make sure you have enabled the 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' feature. (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I cannot enable the Windows feature Hyper-V Platform. And when i check the SystemInfo : Hyper-V Requirements i only have the following line:

```
A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Is there a way that i can run OVB on a Windows 10 VM running on Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Windows Server 2012 doesn't work, but Server 2016 does. Tested on another server, working.